# How to create loading popup which stay 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody help me how to create on function `loading()` ( I have`<div id="l" onclick="loading"></div>`) to show popup with loading gif for 5 seconds (like http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html Simple Modal Window

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
window.setTimeout(function(){window.close()}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into overlays: http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html